# Modificar estructura de datos

Tags: javascript, estructuras-de-datos

Como estan, como realizarian la siguiente conversión

```
const array = [
  {"clave":'1',"count":7},
  {"clave":1,"count":43},
  {"clave":2,"count":229},
  {"clave":2,"count":1 }
]
```

basado en ese objeto necesito transformarlo en el siguiente:

```
{ clave: 1 , count: [7,43]},
{ clave: 2 , count: [229,1]},
```

Saludos

Comment: Porfavor incluye un [mcve], si bien el problema es bastante entendible al menos demuestra el esfuerzo que has hecho, las preguntas de este estilo (que piden soluciones sin una base) no son bien recibidas. Existen diversas formas, te recomiendo usar [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), si te es complejo intenta realizarlo a la antigua, con `for`.

Comment: Adicionalmente te recomiendo realizar el [tour] y ganar tu primera medalla. Saludos.

Comment: Como indica @ricardo-dlc, sería interesante que incluyeras más información. ¿Se trata de leer los objetos clave-contador y crear un nuevo objeto clave-contadores donde contadores es una lista en el mismo orden en que estaban en el array? No parece difícil cuando se formula en lenguaje natural.

Comment: Exacto @sokkian en lenguaje natural resulta simple. No estoy con la PC por eso no puse el código. Básicamente probé mediante los for y con reduce.  Con los for se vuelve poco óptimo cuando las listas contienen muchos datos. Con reduce me aproxime al resultado final pero me está faltando algo.

Answer (score 0):

basado en tu pregunta y en lo que comentas te puedo proponer 2 soluciones:

**Algoritmo ad Hoc**: en este caso basta con crear una sola función donde reduciremos tu array y luego lo mapearemos.

```js
const array = [
  {"key":'1',"count":7},
  {"key":1,  "count":43},
  {"key":2,  "count":229},
  {"key":2,  "count":1 }
]

const groupByKey = objArr => {
  let list = array.reduce( (accu, next) => {
    next.key in accu? 
      accu[next.key].push(next.count) 
      : (accu[next.key] = [next.count])
    return accu;
  },{});
  list = Object.keys(list).map( key => ({ key, count:list[key] }))
  return list
}
    
console.log(groupByKey(array))
```

**Explicación:**

1. Creamos una función que aceptara un array con objetos.
2. Usaremos reduce para agrupar nuestros objetos en uno solo basado en la propiedad llamada "key".
3. En Cada iteración preguntamos si nuestra propiedad "key" ya se encuentra en el objeto final:

- Si no lo esta: Creamos un array y le pasamos como primer item el valor de la propiedad "count" del objeto actual.
- Si lo esta: agregamos la propiedad "count" al array que previamente ya existe.

4. Regresamos nuestro objeto final para la siguiente iteración de reduce, así hasta terminar.
5. Mapeamos todas las propiedades del objeto final para que queden idénticas a la estructura de tus objetos iniciales. Esto es así por que con reduce usamos el valor de "key" como propiedad para agrupar los objetos y no el nombre "key" en si mismo pues seria un poco mas laborioso.

**Algoritmo Genérico**: Sirve para cualquier caso donde tengas un array de objetos y desees agruparlos bajo una propiedad especifica.

```js
const array = [
      {"key":'1',"count":7,  "name": "daniel", },
      {"key":1,  "count":43, "name": "rita",   },
      {"key":2,  "count":229,"name": "natan",  },
      {"key":2,  "count":1,  "name": "daniel", },
      {"key":3,  "count":30, "name": "ricardo",},
      {"key":4,  "count":4,  "name": "rita",   },
      {"key":4,  "count":0,   "name": "memo",  },
      {"key":5,  "count":15,  "name": "daniel",},
]


const PropertiesToArray = (obj, key) => {
    return Object
        .keys(obj)
        .filter(property => property !== key)
        .reduce((accu, next) => {
            accu[next] = [obj[next]];
            return accu;
        }, {});
}

const mergeObjects = (mainObj, subObj) => {
    Object
        .keys(mainObj)
        .forEach(property => mainObj[property].push(subObj[property]))
    return mainObj;
}

const groupByKey = (objArr, key) => {
    let list = objArr.reduce((accu, next) => {
        accu[next[key]] = next[key] in accu ? mergeObjects(accu[next[key]], next) : PropertiesToArray(next, key);
        return accu;
    }, {});
  
    list = Object.keys(list).map(val => ({ [key]: val, ...list[val] }))
    return list
}

//Por llave
console.log(groupByKey(array,'key'));

//Por nombre
console.log(groupByKey(array,'name'));
```

**Explicación:**

1. Creamos una función que aceptara un array con objetos y un "key" en base a como agrupar los objetos.
2. Usaremos reduce para agrupar nuestros objetos en uno solo basado en la propiedad "key" que le pasamos como parámetro.
3. En Cada iteración preguntamos si nuestra propiedad "key" que pasamos ya se encuentra en el objeto final:

- Si no lo esta: pasamos a una función nuestro objeto actual y el "key" por el cual agrupamos, esto con el fin de convertir cada propiedad de nuestro objeto en un array exceptuando la propiedad "key".
- Si lo esta: pasamos a una función por parámetro el objeto que ya se encontraba en objeto final y el nuevo objeto de esta iteración para juntar cada una de sus propiedades como items de un array.

4. Regresamos nuestro objeto final para la siguiente iteración de reduce, así hasta terminar.
5. Mapeamos todas las propiedades del objeto final para que queden idénticas a la estructura de los objetos iniciales. Únicamente la propiedad "key" estará como un valor único, las demás propiedades de cada objeto serán arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente es muy sencillo, solo necesitas [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para crear un nuevo arreglo y recorrer para insertar o modificar cada elemento. Con [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) puedes saber si el elemento actual ya existe en el nuevo arreglo o no, para modificar o insertar:

```js
const array = [
  {"clave":'1',"count":7},
  {"clave":1,"count":43},
  {"clave":2,"count":229},
  {"clave":2,"count":1 }
];

let nuevo = array.reduce((acum, item) => {
    // Verificar si la clave ya existe en el nuevo arreglo
    let index = acum.findIndex(i => item.clave == i.clave);
    // index será -1 si no se encontró el elemento
    if(index < 0) {
        // No existe, hay que insertar y definir count como arreglo
        acum.push({clave: item.clave, count: [item.count]});
    } else {
        // index contiene la posición del elemento encontrado
        // Agregar a count
        acum[index].count.push(item.count);
    }
    return acum;
}, []);

console.log(nuevo);
```